# Blazor - toggle gender name/sign

Tags: blazor, toggle

i'm new on Blazor and trying to toggle the gender(Geschlecht) and would like to have the name, or even better the sign as output. That's what i tried:

```
<p class="mb-0 text-sm text-right">@horse.gender @(horse.gender == "girl" ? "woman" : "man")</p>
```

even better would be, if something like this would work to output the sign:

```
<p class="mb-0 text-sm text-right">@horse.gender @(horse.gender == "girl" ? <i class="fa fa-venus" aria-hidden="true"></i> : <i class="fa fa-mars" aria-hidden="true"></i>)</p>
```

don't know what to do -.-
getting this error: error CS0019 == operator can't on type gender and "string"

Comment: use:  horse.gender == GENDERENUM.Girl or horse.gender.ToString().ToLower() == "girl", the first one is best solution.

Comment: What type is horse.gender? The problem is that horse.gender is not a string, but you try to compare it with the string "girl".

Answer (score 0):

In your code block create a calculated property:

```
string cssClass => horse.Gender == Gender.Girl ? "fa-venus" : "fa-mars";
```

Use it like this:

```
<i class="fa @cssClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```